# Jquery.each array push is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var positions = [];
      $('.category-description TABLE TD').each(function() {
        var fulltxt = $(this).html().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        var lengt = fulltxt.length;
        var indx = $(this).index();
        positions.push[fulltxt];
        alert(positions);
      });
```

I can't understand why it's not working.. Table always have atleast 3 TD's and fulltxt have content. Alert(positions) returns empty result.

Comment: Why are you not using `$(this).text()`???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not work because of a typo

```
positions.push[fulltxt];
              ^       ^
```

should be

```
positions.push(fulltxt);
              ^       ^
```

And it appears you are trying to reinvent [`$(this).text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

You can also use [map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
var positions = $('.category-description TABLE TD')
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  })
  .get();
```